# Which logger to use along with Async await protractor scripts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, protractor

I have been using winston npm module to write logs in protractor. Once the protractor code has been migrated to async, await, there has been lot of synchronisation issues with the logs. (Multiple undefined and zero comes in ). And the execution is also going for a toss.

I have been researching about how to configure  winston configuration to support async await format, but couldn't find anything on this regard.

```
use strict;
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'test';
const logDir = 'log';


///#####loggging levels
//{ error: 0, warn: 1, info: 2, verbose: 3, debug: 4, silly: 5 }

// Create the log directory if it does not exist
if (!fs.existsSync(logDir)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(logDir);
}

const dailyRotateFileTransport =  new transports.DailyRotateFile({
  filename: `${logDir}/%DATE%-results.log`,
  datePattern: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
   maxSize: '20m',
    maxFiles: '14d'
});

const logger = createLogger({
  // change level if in dev environment versus production
  //level: env === 'development' ? 'info' : 'debug',
  //giving level as silly so that all logs are added to the file.
  level: env === 'development' ? 'info' : 'silly',

  format: format.combine(
    format.label({ label: path.basename(module.parent.filename) }),
    format.timestamp({ format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'}),
    format.printf(info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level} [${info.label}]: ${info.message}`)
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.Console({
      level: 'info',
      format: format.combine(
        format.colorize(),
        format.printf(
          info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level} [${info.label}]: ${info.message}`
        )
      )
    }),
    dailyRotateFileTransport,    
  ],
  exceptionHandlers: [
    new transports.File({ filename: 'exceptions.log' })
  ]
});
module.exports = logger;
```

The above config file, works perfectly while working with promise based protractor scripts but goes for a toss, when async await comes into picture.

any suggestions or pointers would be a great help.

Comment: If you need a simple logger, I like loglevel.

Comment: Are you using Winston V2 or V3?

Comment: I use this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug. Doesn't seem to have any issues with `async` / `await`